# How to get text from a textarea we entered using selenium

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I get the text that I entered in a text-area using Selenium where the text entered in the developer options in Chrome and Mozilla where in IE its visible in the developer section. Using gettext() I am able to get the text from IE but giving me nothing using the same for Chrome and Mozilla.

```
string text = 
       driver.findelement(
           by.xpath("//textarea[@placeholder='E‌​nter a description']")
       ).gettext();
```

Comment: Show us your code :)

Comment: string text=driver.findelement(by.xoath("//textarea[@placeholder='Enter a description']")).gettext();

Comment: what you have tired. Please show your code

Comment: U can see the code above @shailendra. I want to get the text entered in a textarea which is not displayed in the developer options in chrome and mozilla

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String text=driver.findelement(By.xpath("//textarea[@placeholder='E‌​nter a description']")).getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: tried that too, no use. Actually it didnt have attribute 'Value'.

Comment: @ManiKanta, did you get exception with this code or you get empty string?

Comment: @ManiKanta Please note that the attribute is case-sensitive. Make sure that it's "value" and not "Value". Is it the same that way too?

Comment: @skandigraun I gave as 'Value'.

Comment: @Anderson I am getting empty string , no exception.

Comment: Sorry @ShubhasmitGupta I am not able to post it as I in another network from which I cant give.

Comment: @ManiKanta That's my point exactly. It has to be "value" with all lower case and not "Value".

Comment: @ManiKanta: As skandigraun pointed. Please change it to 'value' and try.

Answer (score 0):

One of the below attributes should get the text using following :

- text
- textContent
- innerText
- innerHTML
- nodeValue
- value

Answer (score 0):

Providing vague solution since it is difficult to suggest without HTML

```
String text=driver.findelement(By.xpath("//textarea[@placeholder='E‌​nter a description']")).getAttribute("innerHTML")//or .getAttribute("outerHTML") ;
```

Use string functions to get the required value!